# Is it possible to set Postgres Isolation level for SSIS pipeline?

Tags: postgresql, ssis, transactions, odbc, isolation-level

I need everything read in my SSIS pipeline from a Postgres source to be a snapshot.

The transactional DB guys told me SET TRANSACTION REPEATABLE READ using a transaction will allow me to achieve this.

I had a look at the ODBC driver but I don't see anything relevant.
Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Likely what you're looking to do is

Edit the ODBC connection manager and set the RetainSameConnection property to True. This should ensure that only one connection is opened and it's held open for the package duration.

Add an explicit Execute SQL Task. The statement here would set the transaction isolation level so if `SET TRANSACTION REPEATABLE READ` is valid postgres syntax, then put that there.

Data flow as normal. Since you've already established the isolation level, the ODBC source component would continue in that level..

You might also look at specifying it withing the ODBC source component - but this would also require you to write your source query instead of picking a table in the dropdown.

Comment: Sweet, that sounds doable. Didnt think of the retain connection option. I didnt think it would accept I could prefix the source query with the set command, something to experiment. Thanks for posting!

Comment: It's a complete guess on my part as to whether this _works_ with PG, just laying out how people have implemented it with SQL Server isolation levels and explicit transactions